# Blank Pages with # URL & Google

Tags: pages, urls, navigation, seo, noindex

I'm using some blank pages that have a title only and a URL set to '#' for my navigation. (So, that the item appears in the dropdown menu, but when it's clicked a page doesn't open).

Do I need to make sure that Google doesn't try to index these pages? I don't want to be penalized by Google. Should it be a concern?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Mike, Thank you for adding the tags-- hadn't thought of those.

Answer (score 1):

Google knows what these are - you do not need to worry.